# App Engine Standard / Expressjs / app.yaml - serving static files - files aren't found?

Tags: app.yaml, google-appengine-node

I have a node/express app on App Engine Standard.
If I serve the static files using express.static everything works as expected.

Now, I want to reduce the overhead on the app by serving of static files as described here:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/serving-static-files?tab=node.js#serving_from_your_application

So far, no luck getting this to work. I'm hoping someone can see where I'm going wrong.

The deployed directory structure is:

```
App Engine:/
  /dist
    /public
      /img
  /node_modules
  /src
...
```

and I'm trying to serve images so that
www.my_app.com/img/picture.jpg doesn't hit express.static with this in my app.yaml:

```
handlers:
    - url: /img
      static_dir: dist/public/img
    - url: /.*
      script: auto
```

The images are all returning 404 errors. The handler url is matching correctly because the app engine log has this warning:

```
Static file referenced by handler not found: /dist/public/img/picture.jpg
```

The app.yaml docs (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/reference/app-yaml?tab=node.js) state that static_dir is "The path to the directory containing the static files, from the application root directory."

I'm assuming the application root directory would be App Engine:/  but just in case, I also tried defining static_dir as

```
static_dir: public/img
```

which also doesn't work.

So, I'm missing something important and it's driving me bananas :(